# I Get an Error When I Leave VB.NET Datagrid Cell Value as Null

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagrid

I get a 'Conversion from type DBNull to String is not valid' error when I proceed to insert the row with a null cell value from my program to MS Sql Server even if the column is already set to accept null values in the database. How do I solve this?

FYI I'm using an unbound datagrid, and I get all the screen values during runtime.

```
Property SerialNo() 
    Get 
        Return strSerialNo 
    End Get 

    Set(ByVal value) 
        strSerialNo = value <-----this is where I get the error 
    End Set 
End Property
```

Comment: Where does the error occur? What's the stack trace?

Comment: It occurs when I set the value in my get-set class

Comment: That's called a property.  What's the stack trace?  Please show us the code.

Comment: Property SerialNo()
        Get
            Return strSerialNo
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value)
            strSerialNo = value <-----this is where I get the error
        End Set
    End Property

Comment: You should enable `Option Explicit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare a type for your property:

```
Property SerialNo As String
```

Comment: That was it! I am ashamed.. I'm sorry to have wasted your time